# Natively embed dash application into a php site

Tags: php, reactjs, curl, single-sign-on, plotly-dash

I am trying to natively embed plotly dash application into a website that's built using php. My dash application is deployed to Heroku and I'd like natively embed this to the website with SSO.

I can use authenticate the user with a login API using a cURL call.

Currently, I am using `<iframe>` which is a hacky and doesn't authenticate the user. Are there any solutions to this problem? Can dash App be compiled into a react web component or something else?